# Simple form, trying to post to database

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I have a form, with jquery validation, and a captcha, and I am having trouble posting to a database.  I am new at this, my code is ugly, and I have two attempts at this.  both fail.  I think I am mixing up OO and procedural styles.

1st code

```
<?php
  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "x";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
         "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
  } else {
$mysqli = new MySQLi("x","x","x","x");

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
                echo "failed to connect to db" . mysqli_connect_error();
                exit();
                }
$cf_firstname=$_POST[cf_firstname];
$cf_lastname=$_POST[cf_lastname];   
$cf_address=$_POST[cf_address];
$cf_address2=$_POST[cf_address2];
$cf_city=$_POST[cf_city];
$cf_state=$_POST[cf_state];
$cf_zipcode=$_POST[cf_zipcode];
$cf_contact1=$_POST[cf_contact1];
$cf_contact2=$_POST[cf_contact2];
$cf_contact3=$_POST[cf_contact3];
$cf_message=$_POST[cf_message];
$cf_email=$_POST[cf_email];
$cf_phone=$_POST[cf_phone];
$cf_sale=$_POST[cf_sale];   
$sql="INSERT INTO Contacts (`cf_firstname`, `cf_lastname`, `cf_address`, `cf_address2`, `cf_city`, `cf_state`, `cf_zipcode`, `cf_contact1`, `cf_contact2`, `cf_contact3`, `cf_message`, `cf_email`, `cf_phone`, `cf_sale`) VALUES ($cf_firstname,$cf_lastname,$cf_address,$cf_address2,$cf_city,$cf_state,$cf_zipcode,$cf_contact1,$cf_contact2,$cf_contact3,$cf_message,$cf_email,$cf_phone,$cf_sale)"; 

$result = $mysqli->query($sql);     
if (!$result) {
    printf("%s\n", $mysqli->error());
    exit();
}
echo "query run" ;


$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
  }






?>
```

Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::error() Line 38

Second try

```
<?php
  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "x";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
         "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
  } else {
$mysqli = new MySQLi("x");

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
                echo "failed to connect to db" . mysqli_connect_error();
                exit();
                }
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Contacts (cf_firstname, `cf_lastname`, `cf_address`, `cf_address2`, `cf_city`, `cf_state`, `cf_zipcode`, `cf_contact1`, `cf_contact2`, `cf_contact3`, `cf_message`, `cf_email`, `cf_phone`, `cf_sale`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"); 
echo $mysqli->error;            
$stmt->bind_param("ssssssssssssss",$cf_firstname,$cf_lastname,$cf_address,$cf_address2,$cf_city,$cf_state,$cf_zipcode,$cf_contact1,$cf_contact2,$cf_contact3,$cf_message,$cf_email,$cf_phone,$cf_sale);     
    $cf_firstname=$_POST[cf_firstname];
    $cf_lastname=$_POST[cf_lastname];
    $cf_address=$_POST[cf_address];
    $cf_address2=$_POST[cf_address2];
    $cf_city=$_POST[cf_city];
    $cf_state=$_POST[cf_state];
    $cf_zipcode=$_POST[cf_zipcode];
    $cf_contact1=$_POST[cf_contact1];
    $cf_contact2=$_POST[cf_contact2];
    $cf_contact3=$_POST[cf_contact3];
    $cf_message=$_POST[cf_message];
    $cf_email=$_POST[cf_email];
    $cf_phone=$_POST[cf_phone];
    $cf_sale=$_POST[cf_sale];
    echo $mysqli->error;

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
  }






?>
```

no errors that i can find, but does not post to database.

I am using DW5.5, is there something better for this kind of thing?

Is OO or procedural style just a choice? Is one style better at some things?

I am mostly copying examples to learn and get this thing working, I am stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example looks pretty good. Don't be intimidated by error messages- they are there to help. "Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::error() Line 38" means on line 38 you tried to do something that, according to php, is a non-existant function.

"undefined method mysqli::error()" is your clue. Look at example 1 on how to employ mysqli in the php manual, it may end up solving your issue!

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

The fact that you make it to line 38 leads me to believe that your code up to that point is actually good. However, My first step would be to replace all of the code in the INSERT statement with hard coded values and see if that works. If it does, that means that whatever data you have coming in dynamically is messing up your query (and that's the most likely answer, in my experience).

Comment: Also, VALIDATE THE INPUT! That's a whole other topic though, so that's all I'll say here.